# How to run OpenGL version 3.3 (with Intel HD 4000) on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu-15.04

Running the command glxinfo | grep OpenGL shows

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.7.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.7.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

I have the Intel HD 4000 graphic card which can support OpenGL 3.3 according to the sources on internet.

Simply, what should I do so that glxinfo shows version 3.3 so that I may proceed to learn modern graphics programming?

Comment: Did you install any graphics driver?

Comment: update `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` and ensure `kms` is enabled, dont know the state of fglrx, I cancel it's use years ago...Also VMWare drivers instead of X ??, don't know what you'll get in virtual env...

Comment: @Jerem  
inside of VM?..is there a way to do it?

Comment: @j-p
what will this update do?...what is kms?
"Also VMware drivers instead of X??"  ...what do you mean?

Comment: this would have updated the not 'mesa' part or the driver stack, your mesa version being recent enough to get 3.3gl, but as datewolf said, inside vm, this is useless. for kms, see: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_mode-setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running in a VM. GPUs usually are not passed through to the VM and all you get is a shim-driver supporting only a lower OpenGL version, which commands are passed through the VM to the host.

Solution: Run Linux natively on your box.

Comment: @PriyamAgarwal: Well, you could force Mesa into softpipe mode by uninstalling the VMware graphics drivers, or create a custom Mesa build supporting only softpipe.